# Create a Button with only code AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

I feel like something like this exists but how would I create a button in **only action script 3 code**? I mean **without** making a shape and converting it to a button symbol or something. It would probably make it easier to only work in FlashDevelop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `SimpleButton` class or roll your own using the `Sprite` class. Then you can draw anything or use any image as the button and it's over, down and default states.

For example a simple button can be like this :

```
var goButton:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();

var myButtonSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
myButtonSprite.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x555555);
myButtonSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xff000,1);
myButtonSprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,200,30);
myButtonSprite.graphics.endFill();

goButton.overState = goButton.downState = goButton.upState = goButton.hitTestState = myButtonSprite;
addChild(goButton);
```

You can have different display objects for each state of the button or you can attach bitmaps instead of sprites.

Comment: Many thanks! I gave my simplebutton a height, width, x and y. it's known as
`private var goButton:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();`
it doesn't show on the stage though, how could I give it a background color or border?