# Adobe CC Flash AS3 Click tag

Tags: actionscript-3

I recently switched over from Adobe CS6 to Adobe CC. In the new Adobe CC Flash, it no longer supports action script 2. I need to create an AS3, click tag. Is there a universal AS3 clickTag code you know of that is used? I've googled it, but found some unreliable results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean you want to have a button react to a click? If so, you simply have to create a button object, and then add a listener for that button where you choose 1) the event you want to listen for, in this case a click, and 2) the code you wish to execute when that event is fired, in most cases this is a function call.

For exaxmple, the following code was placed on the first frame of an .FLA:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var myButton:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
var myButtonSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
myButtonSprite.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x555555);
myButtonSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xff000,1);
myButtonSprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,200,30);
myButtonSprite.graphics.endFill();
myButton.overState = myButton.downState = myButton.upState = myButton.hitTestState = myButtonSprite;

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClickHandler);
addChild(myButton);

function buttonClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("YAY! My Button was clicked!");   
}
```

To give credit where it is due, the code for creating the button dynamically that you see above is showcased here: [Create a Button with only code AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291350/create-a-button-with-only-code-as3)

If you already have a button on your stage that you want to wire up with a click event you simply have to give the button an instance name and then use that instance name in the code.  In the following example, the instance name of the button on the stage is myButton:

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClickHandler);

function buttonClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("YAY! My Button was clicked!");   
}
```